# Nintex / SharePoint upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-2010, nintex-workflow

My team is embarking on moving from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2016 with Nintex. They want to move content on an individual basis.

However, we also need to move running workflows and keep these intact.

What's the process of moving Nintex workflows and lists from SP2010 to a SharePoint 2016 environment?
Need to ensure the workflows/lists remain with the correct status

Thanks

Comment: I would refer to Nintex's own documentation and support for this process: https://community.nintex.com/docs/DOC-1088

Answer (score 0):

You cannot move running workflows in SharePoint. The best suggestion is to pause or end the workflow, save the status and then kick them off after you move them. I recommend trying to complete whatever process is running before moving that content or workflow. This means scheduling the migration around business processes or informing your users that SharePoint will be down for a period of time. You can also copy the workflow and list over to the new site and have users start using that one while you wind down the old site. A tool like Sharegate is good for this type of stuff.